# Hide & Re-display Customized Pop-up Switchboard in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

After fiddling around with the Switchboard Manager a few times, I decided to create a customized pop-up switchboard form instead. The problem I'm having now is the switchboard displays in front of my other forms and reports.

Can anyone recommend a way to hide the switchboard after the user has clicked an option and then re-display the switchboard after the user has exited out of the chosen form or report? Also, I welcome any tips/tricks/advice with customized switchboards.

Comment: do `.hide` and `.show` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `Me.Visible = False` to any button_Click event on your switchboard that you want to hide the switchboard.

Then in the `Form_Close()` event for the other forms, use the following to show the switchboard again.

```
Application.Forms("SwitchboardName").Visible = True
```